# Error Message: Cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [True] of <class 'bool'>

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

data = pd.read_csv('survey_export_Client_feedback_Dec_20_2020.csv', index_col = 'Email')
data.head()
```

Then I get this:
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [True] of <class 'bool'>

Please why is this so, i need some help. thanks.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCUzk.jpg)

Comment: Can you show us a few rows from the .csv?

Comment: ok, i will put on up.

Comment: can you open it with notepad instead of microsoft excel and paste some rows here?

Comment: I have uploaded a new one.